# Как выбирать поведение класса в зависимости от типов, переданных в шаблоны

Tags: c++, шаблоны-с++, метапрограммирование

К примеру у меня есть класс `A` с шаблонным параметром `T`

```
template<typename T>
class A{
   int test;
};
```

Я хочу чтоб тип поля `test` определялся в зависимости от типа `T`. К примеру, если `T` - `double`, то `test` - `string`, иначе `test` - `int`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Специализация шаблона, показанная в соседнем ответе, удобна если нужно заменить бо́льшую часть содержимого класса. Все, что менять не нужно, придется копипастить.

А если нужно поменять только тип одного поля, то можно так:

```
template <typename T>
class A
{
    std::conditional_t<std::is_same_v<T, double>, std::string, int> test;
};
```

Comment: А возможно еще назначать случай, если не то не то, то выбирать это. Иными словами сделать else

Comment: @DenverToha Можно вкладывать несколько `std::conditional_t` один в другой. Правда смотреться будет громоздко.

Answer (score 4):

```
template<typename T>
class A{
   int test;
};

template<>
class A <double>{
   string test;
};
```